# Mi campo input mantiene el primer valor que le dí

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Os comento en mi página web tengo una tabla de comentarios, en la cual puedo agregar nuevos comentarios o responder a los ya existentes, Para esto último, he añadido un botón al lado de cada comentario que mediante Ajax muestra un form con un campo de texto, agrega la respuesta y la muestra al momento. El problema es que cuando cierro ese formulario, si lo vuelvo a abrir y escribo otra cosa totalmente distinta, se inserta otra respuesta al comentario, pero con el texto del primero y no con lo ultimo que he escrito:

Os muestro mi codigo:

Aqui para mostrar el formulario al pulsar el boton:

```
        $("#responderComent1").click(function(){
        if(contador < 1){
            contador++;
        $(this).before('<form action="javascript:void(0);" class="formRespuesta"><input type="text" id="resp1"/><button class="enviarComent1">✔</button></form>');
        $(this).before('<button class="cerrarComent">❌</button>');
        $(this).hide();
        }
    });
```

A continuación el botón que cierra el form:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.cerrarComent', function(){
        contador--;
        $(this).hide();
        $(".responderComent").show();
        $(".formRespuesta").hide();
    });
```

Y aqui el código Ajax que procesa la respuesta:

```
$(document).on('click', '.enviarComent1', function(){
    var texto = $("#resp1").val();
    var idComentario = $("#responderComent1").val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "procesarRespuestasComentario.php",
        data: {texto:texto, idComentario:idComentario},
        success:function(r){
            $('#respuestas1').html(r);
        }
    });
});
```

He probado a realizar getElementByClassName("formRespuesta").reset(), a darle val('') pero nada, el reset no hace nada y darle val '' al campo input lo único que hace es que cuando envíe otro, ponga lo que ponga salga vacío ('')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando hagas `$(".formRespuesta").hide();`, la primera forma permanece en la página. Entonces `var texto = $("#resp1").val();` leeré el contenido de la primera forma en lugar de la segunda. Si utilizas

```
$(document).on('click', '.enviarComent1', function(){
    var texto = $(this).parents("form").find("#resp1");
```

Leerá el contenido de `input` correcto.

Además, los `id` deben de ser unicos. Será mas correcto si usas `class="resp1"` y `find(".resp1")`

Comment: Perfecto! Me ha solucionado todo y funcionando perfectamente. Tuve que leer un poco sobre parents() ya que no lo conocía pero muchas gracias! El tema del id es porque tengo varios para diferenciar y tal.